# Text not wrapping inside a div element

Tags: css, word-wrap, htmltext

I am experiencing a problem that never happened before and seems really unprecedented, some text is not wrapping inside a div.

In this link is a sample of my html code:

http://jsfiddle.net/NDND2/2/

```
<div id="calendar_container">
   <div id="events_container">  
      <div class="event_block">
         <div class="title">
            lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Any help??

Comment: It does wrap if you add spaces, your fiddle is not like the code posted here

Comment: Your example is extreme and does not match your HTML

Answer (score 92, accepted):

That's because there are no spaces in that long string so it has to break out of its container. Add `word-break:break-all;` to your .title rules to force a break.

```
#calendar_container > #events_container > .event_block > .title {
    width:400px;
    font-size:12px;
    word-break:break-all;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
  background-color: #ff8582;
  color: white;
}

#calendar_container {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#calendar_container>#events_container {
  width: 400px;
}

#calendar_container>#events_container>.event_block {
  width: 400px;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  background-color: #009;
}

#calendar_container>#events_container>.event_block>.title {
  width: 400px;
  font-size: 12px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div id="calendar_container">
  <div id="events_container">
    <div class="event_block">
      <div class="title">kjskjsfkjsfkjfkjdfkjdkfjdkfjjkdjfkdjfkdjfkdjfkdjfkdjfkdjfkdjfkdjfkdjfkdjfkdjfkdjfkdjfjdjdjdjd</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 132):

I found this helped where my words were breaking part way through the word in a WooThemes Testimonial plugin.

```
.testimonials-text {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

play with it here http://nortronics.com.au/recomendations/

```
<blockquote class="testimonials-text" itemprop="reviewBody">

<a href="http://www.jacobs.com/" class="avatar-link">

<img width="100" height="100" src="http://nortronics.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/SKM-100x100.jpg" class="avatar wp-post-image" alt="SKM Sinclair Knight Merz">

</a>
<p>Tim continues to provide high-level technical applications advice and support for a very challenging IP video application. He has shown he will go the extra mile to ensure all avenues are explored to identify an innovative and practical solution.<br>Tim manages to do this with a very helpful and professional attitude which is much appreciated.
</p>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: it does wrap my text which now fit into the div

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the OP's question. Adding `white-space: normal;` to any element in the example does nothing.

Answer (score 10):

The problem in the jsfiddle is that your dummy text is all one word.  If you use your lorem ipsum given in the question, then the text wraps fine.

If you want large words to be broken mid-word and wrap around, add this to your .title css:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Answer (score 8):

This may help a small percentage of people still scratching their heads. Text copied from clipboard into VSCode may have an invisible hard space character preventing wrapping. Check it with HTML inspector

[image: string with hard spaces]

Comment: Gosh...for me this was the reason. Tnx!

Comment: This was the case for me and doing `string.replace(/&nbsp;/g, " ")` allows the string to wrap.

Answer (score 6):

you can add this line: `word-break:break-all;` to your CSS-code

Answer (score 1):

Might benefit you to be aware of another option, `word-wrap: break-word;`

The difference here is that words that can completely fit on 1 line will do that, vs. being forced to break simply because there is no more real estate on the line the word starts on.

See the fiddle for an illustration http://jsfiddle.net/Jqkcp/